# Controversial __set_task_state(tsk, state_value) macro syntax in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor

I came across this syntax in several macros, in `linux kernel 2.4.31` files, but to keep things in focus I am asking regarding `__set_task_state(tsk, state_value)` macro defined in `include/linux/sched.h`:

```
#define __set_task_state(tsk, state_value)      \
    do { (tsk)->state = (state_value); } while (0)
```

What is the "advantage" of defining the above macro with the `do while(0)` statement ? Any side effects ?
It's more convenient to define it like so :

```
#define __set_task_state(tsk, state_value)  (tsk)->state = (state_value)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros)

Comment: `__set_task_state(tsk, state) + 1;` is a good example. With `do {} while(0)` that's an error. Without, `tsk->state` is going to be set to some strange value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reason is for the *if-else* statements. If you use it like this without the *do-while(0)* in the macro:

```
if (check)
  __set_task_state(tsk, state_value);
else
  do_something_else;
```

The compiler will complain because of a "else" without associated "if" (e.g. orphan "else") as the macro expansion will translate the above code as two instructions under the "if" without braces:

```
if (check)
  (tsk)->state = (state_value);; <-- The double ";;" separates two instructions under the "if".
                                 <-- This makes the following "else" orphan
                                 <-- This requires to add braces to fix the compilation error
else
  do_something_else;
```

The *do-while(0)* in the macro makes the grouped instructions appear as a single instruction. Here the expansion is:

```
if (check)
  do { (tsk)->state = (state_value); } while(0); <-- Here, there is a single instruction under the "if"
                                                 <-- So the following "else" is syntactically correct
                                                 <-- No need to add braces
else
  do_something_else;
```

**N.B.**: This tip is normally used to group several instructions in a macro to make them appear as a single instruction:

```
#define MACRO() do { inst1; inst2; inst3;...; } while (0)
```

This makes the following work without the need of braces:

```
if (check)
  MACRO();
else
  do_something_else;
```

This **also avoid severe hidden bugs** like this one for example:

```
while(check)
  MACRO();
```

Without the *do-while(0)* construct, only the first instruction (i.e. *inst1*) would be executed in the *while(check)* loop!

In this [link](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/c_preprocessor.html), there are additional tips to avoid traps with the c-preprocessor. The above tip is described in [§3](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/c_preprocessor.html#3._Group_instructions).

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two reasons for defining it using `do-while` instead of without it.

First, if you define it without `do-while` then the macro can be used as a function that returns value. If you don't like that you should use `do-while` wrapper even for single statement macros.

Second reason is similar. If you define it without wrapper then you can use it to assign value:
`set_task_state(my_task, state) = different_state;`

It would be perfectly legal, but very confusing for anyone reading your code. It works because this expands to:
`(my_task)->state = (state) = different_state;`

Answer (score 1):

Since this macro expands to a single line it doesn't make much sense, but there is a side effect, using the `do ...` version makes the expression not assignable in both directions:

```
state = __set_task_state(tsk, state_value); // syntax error in the do version


__set_task_state(tsk, state_value) = state; // syntax error in the do version
```